# Dual instability, degeneracy, tailing off effect - Which are the causes and which are the effects?

Tags: linear-programming, column-generation, simplex, dantzig-wolfe-decomposition

Dual instability, degeneracy, and the tailing off effect are often mentioned together in papers. However, I cannot seem to find a clear explanation on which of these cause the other and vice versa? How are they connected? Are there any other phenomena that should be included in the mix to explain the chain of effects?